# Crystal Report: Determine the index of subreport

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

How to determine the index of subreport in Crystal Report. I am kinda confused because I have multiple subreports attached in my main report. and the program encounters an error "`This field name is not known."` pointing out the formula `"if NOT(isNull({CIRSourceOfIncome.Subject})) and isNumeric({CIRSourceOfIncome.Subject}) then toNumber({CIRSourceOfIncome.Subject})"` my hunch is I am not calling the correct index of the subreport.

this is the code calling all of the sub reports

```
cryRpt.Subreports(0).SetDataSource(dsAppAdd)
cryRpt.Subreports(1).SetDataSource(dsSpoAdd)
cryRpt.Subreports(2).SetDataSource(dsFIParents)
cryRpt.Subreports(3).SetDataSource(dsFISiblings)
cryRpt.Subreports(4).SetDataSource(dsFIChildren)
cryRpt.Subreports(5).SetDataSource(dsSourceOfIncome)
cryRpt.Subreports(6).SetDataSource(dsBus)
cryRpt.Subreports(7).SetDataSource(dsExp)
cryRpt.Subreports(8).SetDataSource(dsGatheredInfo)
cryRpt.SetParameterValue("dispoIncome", disIncome.ToString)
```

Comment: The subreport has a property "Name". Use it (in a switch case).

Comment: Problem Solved chaged it to `cryRpt.Subreports("AppAdd.rpt").SetDataSource(dsAppAdd)` and so on